# Как устроено получение значения в Dictionary C# c коллизиями

Tags: c#, словари

Я изучаю словари в C# и не могу разобраться с коллизиями. Когда происходит происходит вставка нового значения но происходит коллизия создается однонаправленный список. Но тогда как происходит получение старого значения. Сравнивает ключи?
[image: Вставка с коллизией]

Comment: Да, сравнивает ключи: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs#L305